# adding correlation coefficients?

Tags: correlation, biostatistics

I am running a simulation model with three variables where I need to specify their correlation structure: a, b, and c

I have known expected positive correlation values for a with b and b with c. Based on biological reasons I expect the correlation of a with c to be 1/2 of the correlation of a with b. I want to calculate the expected correlation value of a with c due to the biological reasons combined with the nuisance association of a with c due to the correlation of b with c. I understand that correlation coefficients are not additive but that coefficients of determination are (http://documentation.statsoft.com/STATISTICAHelp.aspx?path=Basicstats/BasicStatistics/Overview/Correlations/CorrelationsIntroductoryOverviewArecorrelationcoefficientsadditive). The solution I am thinking of using is to convert the expected correlation values into coefficients of determination, add them together and then take the square root. Is this correct?

Put another way with a worked example:

- correlation of a with b = 0.74
- correlation of b with c = 0.12
- biologically we expect correlation of a with c to be half of a with b (0.74/2)
- expected correlation of a with c=
  square root of ((0.74/2)^2+(0.74*0.12)^2)=0.3805

**Update, answering Michael's question about how I know so much a priori information about the correlations**:
The short answer is that I have actual data which I have analyzed, but I am running simulations to try to get at how robust various modeling techniques are when making different assumptions about what the true values should. The longer answer is that this is about work involving paternal and grandpaternal ages influencing offspring and grandoffspring telomere lengths (see doi: 10.1073/pnas.1202092109). In my case a is telomere length, b is paternal age and c is grandpaternal age. The actual correlation values are different (I tried to make this a more general problem and with different values to try to avoid the details which I thought might make it more complex). There are biological reasons to expect that the grandpaternal age will be exactly 1/2 of the paternal age effect. I am more confident in the paternal age effect and the correlation between paternal age and grandpaternal age is known. I am trying to simulate whether it is best to control for paternal age when estimating grandpaternal age effect on TL.